# How does Reverse work in Golang under the hood?

Tags: go, reverse

```
s := []string{"Zeno", "John", "Al", "Jenny"}

sort.Sort(sort.Reverse(sort.StringSlice(s)))
```

I could not understand the logic of `Reverse`

The source code for Reverse seems as follows:

```
func Reverse(data Interface) Interface {
    return &reverse{data}
}
```

```
type reverse struct {
    // This embedded Interface permits Reverse to use the methods of
    // another Interface implementation.
    Interface
}
```

```
type Interface interface {
    // Len is the number of elements in the collection.
    Len() int

    // Less reports whether the element with index i
    // must sort before the element with index j.
    //
    // If both Less(i, j) and Less(j, i) are false,
    // then the elements at index i and j are considered equal.
    // Sort may place equal elements in any order in the final result,
    // while Stable preserves the original input order of equal elements.
    //
    // Less must describe a transitive ordering:
    //  - if both Less(i, j) and Less(j, k) are true, then Less(i, k) must be true as well.
    //  - if both Less(i, j) and Less(j, k) are false, then Less(i, k) must be false as well.
    //
    // Note that floating-point comparison (the < operator on float32 or float64 values)
    // is not a transitive ordering when not-a-number (NaN) values are involved.
    // See Float64Slice.Less for a correct implementation for floating-point values.
    Less(i, j int) bool

    // Swap swaps the elements with indexes i and j.
    Swap(i, j int)
}
```

How do those given operations above induce the given array to be reversed?

Comment: Look at the implementation of this interface for `reverse`. I'm betting it simply inverts the logic of `Less`.

Comment: All of the implementations related to the question have been listed already, mate. If anything is missing, you can notify me for sure.

Comment: The [reverse.Less](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/sort/sort.go#L260) method swaps the argument order when calling the underlying Less method.

Comment: @ibrahimkoz The implementation of the interface is missing. What you posted is the declaration. It has signatures for a few methods, but where is the code of those methods?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev There is no implementation for `Interface`, it applies to any sequence of any type.

Comment: @ibrahimkoz You clearly are confused about `interface` and `sort.Interface`. Those are different things. Anyhow, @Cerise has posted a link to the implementation that answers the question (and confirms my guess)

Comment: No, I am not confused about them at all. You can check what is defined for Interface above.

Comment: @ibrahimkoz: "There is no implementation for Interface" - Yes, you are confused. At least, in what interfaces are and how they work. Every collection you wish to sort must implement `Interface` (fully known as `sort.Interface`). Or else you can't sort it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the sort.StringSlice type, you can see it implements the Less method, notice the comparison x[i] < x[j], which means smaller element goes first.

```
func (x StringSlice) Less(i, j int) bool { return x[i] < x[j] }
```

And then notice the sort.reverse type (not sort.Reverse interface), it also implements the Less method but see how it passes the i and j arguments, receives i and j but passes j and i, which is just equivalent to x[i] > x[j]

```
// Less returns the opposite of the embedded implementation's Less method.
func (r reverse) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return r.Interface.Less(j, i)
}
```